# Exposure rate equation variables

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, nuclear-physics, radiation, nuclear-engineering

[image]

I recently saw this equation for the exposure rate in the absence of shielding but couldn't quite find what "A" means in this context. Would anyone happen to know what the "A" variable is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A is the source activity. Read more about it at : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_exposure